# Sending additional query string when triggering a sign-in operation in WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I am building a webassembly app with the latest Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0. I am using Auth0 for the identity provider and I need to pass additional parameters (email address) along with the required parameters defined in OidcProviderOptions when triggering a sign-in operation.

Is there any way to add this additional field so that it goes to the identity provider alongside the existing query-string parameters such as the returnUrl?

The idea is that the Identity provider will read this additional querying (email address) and populate the user-id field when generating the login screen.
I am using the below extension to register the provider

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue sounds a lot like my issue on dotnet/aspnetcore: [WebAssembly.Authentication - Not possible to define "Audience"](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23606)

I solved this by creating a new **Auth0ProviderOptions** which extends from the **OidcProviderOptions** and defining `extraQueryParams`.

- See [this link for the class](https://github.com/StefH/Blazor.WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0/blob/master/src/Blazor.WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0/Auth0ProviderOptions.cs)
- See [this link for the complete example project](https://github.com/StefH/Blazor.WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0)

Comment: Thanks Stef, since my parameter which is the email address of the user will be part of application URL (query string), do you think I should be able to read from NavManager and set the value when initialising the application? I had a go but so far no luck.

Comment: Ah, in your case you need to add the email-address dynamically, I'm not sure if that's easy to do. I'll take a look..

Comment: I have got it working by injecting the dependency in the DefaultAuth0ProviderOptionsConfiguration. Thanks